# Export as JSON using BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator

Tags: json, airflow, ndjson

[image]

When I use the BigQuery console manually, I can see that the 3 options when exporting a table to GCS are `CSV`, `JSON (Newline delimited)`, and `Avro`.

With Airflow, when using the `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` operator, what is the correct value to pass to `export_format` in order to transfer the data to GCS as `JSON (Newline delimited)`? Is it simply `JSON`? All examples I've seen online for `BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator` use `export_format='CSV'`, never for JSON, so I'm not sure what the correct value here is. Our use case needs JSON, since the 2nd task in our DAG (after transferring data to GCS) is to then load that data from GCS into our MongoDB Cluster with `mongoimport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_formats_and_compression_types) the three possible formats to which you can export BigQuery query results are: `CSV`, `JSON`, and `Avro` (and this is compatible with the UI drop-down menu).

[image]

I would try with `export_format='JSON'` as you already proposed.

Comment: JSON does work. After setting the bigquery_conn_id, and using `JSON`, everything seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the value export_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON' was required after finding the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationextract and refering to the values for destinationFormat